# App crash on iOS 9.02

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I am populating a tableview which get data from an array. It has multiple selection and reloading multiple times. There's no problem in logic. It works fine  on iOS 7, 8 but crash on iOS 9.02 with this error.

Any solution please ?

> : HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone SpringBoard[48] :
>   UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
>   (UIKitApplication:com.projectname.catalogue[0x743e][369]) :
>   Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone SpringBoard[48] : Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.project_name.catalogue[0x743e]' crashed.
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] : 676658830601:
>   id=com.project_name.catalogue pid=369, state=0
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone ReportCrash[370] : Formulating report
>   for corpse[369] projectname
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone ReportCrash[370] :
>   platform_thread_get_unique_id matched 113197
>
> Oct 14 10:40:06 iPhone ReportCrash[370] : saved type
>   '109_projectname' report (3 of max 25) as
>   /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/project_name_2015-10-14-104006_iPhone.ips
>
> Oct 14 10:40:11 iPhone kernel[0] : AppleARMPMUCharger:
>   limiting USB input current to 500 mA (measured 519 mA)
>
> Oct 14 10:40:11 iPhone kernel[0] : AppleARMPMUCharger:
>   limiting USB input current to 400 mA (measured 513 mA)

Comment: Impossible to say based on that. Why not run it in the debugger to at least find out where it crashes?

Comment: I think it is a iOS 9.0 issue. May be with permission. But not getting any solution.

Comment: You may need to look at the crash report.

Comment: yeah, its arm64,7,7s supported. @skippy

Comment: that's the crash log boss. 
can i see it in more details ? how ?@PhillipMills

Comment: @stack, do you check all differents between coding for 32 vs 64bit? In my case app totally crash after 1th run under 64bit,

Comment: @stack I am getting crash on same. Its ipad ios9 and something to do with maps. iphone app works fine. Did you find solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 9.0 demands compulsory to create property for some classes. For example, I created UIImageView without property. When I accessed Table Cell again and again with multiple reloading, it does not able to save previous value of the property. And then it causes to crashes. But iOS<9.0 does show any crash.

Comment: I don't understand exactly, In my case app crash when push notification handle when app is not running state .